# LaTeX datatool problems

Tags: datatool

I'm using `datatool` package in a LaTeX document. I use it to write labels. I have addresses in a CSV file.

The problem is that I'm unable to write more than 25 labels. It seem like if `datatool` can't load more that 25 lines from CSV.

Any idea?

This is the .cvs file:

```
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
nome,via,,cap,localita,prov
```

and this is the code:

```
\documentclass{letteracdp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage{envlab}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage [normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\DTLloaddb{indirizzi}{/home/kde/Dropbox/associazione/documenti/ind_sas.csv}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makelabels
%
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach*{indirizzi}{%
\nome=nome,\cognome=cognome,\via=via,\civico=civico,\cap=cap,\localita=localita,\prov=prov,}{
%
\begin{letter}{\emph{\textbf{\nome \space }\\\via\space \\\textbf{\cap},\space \localita\space  \prov}}
%
\end{letter}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: I'm certain that datatools can read more than 25 entries. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example document and the first 26 lines of your data file?

Comment: yes I can. Can I upload file? Or do I have to make it via private messages?

Comment: @user7143: You should edit your question to include the code.

Comment: done. Is it enough ? I Also receive a lot of error on the compilation, but the .pdf is produced.

Comment: I put your code in a code block to make it easier to see.  I presume that the `.csv` stuff is what is loaded by the line `\DTLloaddb`, is that right?

Comment: @Jake and user7143: Whoops!  I think there's some funny editing going on here.  I think that *my* edit got the code blocks right.  The (empty!) quote shouldn't be there, the "and this is the code" should be in ordinary text, and the backticks shouldn't be there in the `.csv` section (the indentation takes care of the code there).

Comment: @Andrew: You're absolutely right. I just removed the first backtick that caused the code to break across lines incorrectly, but missed the closing backtick. I've reverted to your version.

Comment: sorry, I'm not friendly with this forum. I've decouverted just now this last 4 answer :-(. So the prob may be on the code? ehat i have to correct?

Comment: yes, is the .csv that is loaded by the |DTLloadlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV file is wrong, as it misses the header; moreover you are declaring more fields than are contained in the records. Adding the line

```
nome,via,civico,cap,localita,prov
```

as the first in the CSV file and correcting the command into

```
\DTLforeach*{indirizzi}{%
\nome=nome,\via=via,\civico=civico,\cap=cap,\localita=localita,\prov=prov}{%
\begin{letter}{\emph{\textbf{\nome \space }}\\
  \via\space\civico \\
  \textbf{\cap},\space \localita\space  \prov}
\opening{Dear \nome}
Some text
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
}
```

the file can be processed regularly. I tried with 49 lines, surely more can be managed.